# openstack shared PCI between numa with SR-IOV

Tags: openstack, numa, openstack-neutron, sr-iov

I'm building SR-IOV supported compute node on `HP 360g8` hardware and i have `Qlogic` interface card, my compute node has 32 core & 32GB memory.

Problem:

when i launch `vm-1` (with flavor 16 vCPU core) on openstack it launch successful on numa0 node and working great. but when i launch `vm-2` same flavor it start and then shutdown itself in few second, in-short i am not able launch instance on `numa1` node because my `PCIe` attach to `numa0` node which i can see in `lstopo` command.

so at present i am going to lose half compute capacity if this is real problem because i can't use numa1 to launch SR-IOV supported instance.

after google i found this link https://blueprints.launchpad.net/nova/+spec/share-pci-device-between-numa-nodes

and according this link if i can set `hw:pci_numa_affinity_policy=preferred` in flavor it will allow me to spin up instance across the numa node but somehow its not working and still i am not able to spin up instance, (it start instance but then shutdown itself)

Any idea what is wrong here?